# Is there a way to delete a branch on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, deployment, heroku

I am using heroku to host my application. With merges and rebases i got 2 different stages of my app.

Local master is different from master on heroku.

pushing to heroku master failed with:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) 
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxx.git'             
 Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the    
 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

is there a way to delete the heroku master?
then i can push it again to heroku master..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can force push

```
git push --force origin master
```

That will overwrite remote master.

You can also delete remote branch by doing this

```
git push origin :master
```

Note the colon before branch name. This command says "take void from local machine and put this instead of remote branch 'master'"

Comment: It's a simple question, and you're welcome :) By the way, the best "thanks" on this site is upvote+accept :)

Comment: I even not understand why i get down votes for this  question ?

Comment: You got only one. But, I'd say, it's for the lack of research. This matter has been covered a thousand times.

Comment: Delete doesn't actually work for Heroku: `! [remote rejected] master (pre-receive hook declined)`. Looks like they explicitly prevent deletion with a pre-receive hook.

Comment: I found their recommended way to *delete* branches is actually to reset the whole remote repository (using `repo:reset` from the heroku-repo plugin) and re-push the branches you do want to keep. They have instructions about it on https://help.heroku.com/O0EXQZTA/how-do-i-switch-branches-from-master-to-main.

Comment: @MuMind Good comment, [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#reset) is the `repo:reset` described. It needs the plugin `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`. This should be the new answer, because as you wrote, Sergio's answer does not help anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I renamed the branch on Heroku from `master` to `main`, and I want to delete the old `master` branch. If I delete the remote `master` branch directly on Heroku, it will be rejected.

The only way I found working is based on [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#reset-a-git-repository) to reset.

Assume your app name is `my-app`. You can reset by

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:reset --app=my-app
```

Note this will remove all branches in Heroku. So you need push to Heroku again by

```
git push heroku main
```

Comment: This should be the answer